# pass a module and class name as an argument to a ruby function

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jruby, factory-bot

Alright, I have the following method:

```
def update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(target_database,target_table,table_name)                  
    RptMcksWorkdb::CtmStagingExtractControl.                                                        
        where(:src_tablename => table_name).                                                                                 
        update(:from_date_dttm => from_date_dttm, :to_date_dttm => to_date_dttm, :sequence_no => 1) 
end
```

I want the target_database and target_table parameters to be module and class names, respectively; Which will then be used in the function in place of `RptMcksWorkdb::CtmStagingExtractControl`.

So my final function would look similar to this:

```
def update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(target_database,target_table,table_name)                  
        target_database::target_table.                                                        
            where(:src_tablename => table_name).                                                                                 
            update(:from_date_dttm => from_date_dttm, :to_date_dttm => to_date_dttm, :sequence_no => 1) 
    end
```

EDIT: Here is my working code:

```
def update_control_table_window(target_database, target_table, table_name)
     model = "#{target_database.camelcase}::#{target_table.camelcase}".constantize
     model.
         where(:src_tablename => table_name).
         update(:from_date_dttm => from_date_dttm, :to_date_dttm => to_date_dttm, :sequence_no => 1)
 end
```

Comment: Thank you but the code I posted doesn't work. The target_table variable doesn't correctly map to the same variable name in my function definition. My question is clearly posted in the title "how to pass a module and class name as an argument"

Comment: What is the *precise* error message you are getting? How are you calling the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on rails,

You could use a combination of [`camelecase`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelcase)/[`classify`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/classify) and [`constantize`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize)

```
> model = "#{'my_database'.camelcase}::#{'here_is_some_table'.camelcase}".constantize
=> MyDatabase::HereIsSomeTable  # Only work if you actually have such a constant
```

that'll give something like

```
def update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(target_database, target_table, table_name)
    model = "#{'target_database'.camelcase}::#{'target_table'.camelcase}".constantize
    model.
        where(src_tablename: table_name).
        update(from_date_dttm: from_date_dttm, to_date_dttm: to_date_dttm, sequence_no: 1)
end
```

Comment: Or you could just `class_name.const_get(constant_name)`. And I would add a minor correction for the OP: Ruby has methods and not functions.

Comment: This worked with some modification. I'm not using rails but we are using the active support gem which seems to be all I needed. I have placed my working code in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just pass the class you want into your method, instead of passing the containing module and the class separately:

```
def update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(target_class, table_name)
  target_class.
    where(src_tablename: table_name).
    update(from_date_dttm: from_date_dttm, to_date_dttm: to_date_dttm, sequence_no: 1)
end

update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(
  RptMcksWorkdb::CtmStagingExtractControl, :customers)
```

Otherwise, you need to reflectively get the value of the constants:

```
def update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(target_database, target_table, table_name)
  const_get(target_database).const_get(target_table).
    where(src_tablename: table_name).
    update(from_date_dttm: from_date_dttm, to_date_dttm: to_date_dttm, sequence_no: 1)
end

update_window_for_ctm_staging_extract(
  :RptMcksWorkdb, :CtmStagingExtractControl, :customers)
```